# Thumbnail Image in lightning Datatable lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I need to display files thumbnail images in my data table in LWC.
I have followed this [blog](https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/show-image-in-lightning-web-component-data-table/), but in my component, I'm getting the URL instead of images.

Below is my code:

thumbNailImage.html:

```
<template>
    <img src={url} alt={altText} class="image"/>
</template>
```

thumbNailImage.js:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ThumbNailImage extends LightningElement {
    @api url;
    @api altText;
}
```

fileManagerDataTable.html:

```
<template>
    
</template>
```

fileManagerDataTable.js:

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import thumbNailImageTable from './thumbNailImageTable';

export default class FileManagerDataTable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        image: {
            template: thumbNailImageTable
        }
    };
}
```

thumbNailImageTable.html:

```
<template>
    <c-thumb-nail-image url={value}
    alt-text="Image Not Found">

    </c-thumb-nail-image>
</template>
```

fileManager.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title='File Manager' icon-name="standard:document">
        <template if:true={isLoading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleFilesChange} value={searchFiles} variant="label-hidden" placeholder="Search Files..."></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Download Selected" title="Download Selected" onclick={downloadSelected} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <lightning-button title="Content Sync" icon-name="utility:refresh"
                onclick={handleRefresh} slot="actions">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        

        <div class="slds-var-p-around_small">
            <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={dataList} columns={columnsList}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

fileManager.js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

import getFilesList from '@salesforce/apex/FileListController.getFilesList';
import deleteContentDocument from '@salesforce/apex/FileListController.deleteContentDocument';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


const columns = [
    // {label: 'Select', fieldName: 'isSelected', type: 'boolean'},
    { label: 'Profile Pic', fieldName: 'contentUrl', type:'image'},
    { label: 'Title',       fieldName: 'title',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: { fieldName: 'icon' }, iconPosition: 'left' 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Created By',  fieldName: 'createdBy',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: 'standard:user', iconPosition: 'left' 
        }
    },
    { label: 'Created Date',  fieldName: 'createdDate',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: 'standard:icon', iconPosition: 'left' 
        }
    },
    { label: 'File Type',  fieldName: 'filetype',
        cellAttributes: { 
            iconName: 'standard:icon', iconPosition: 'left' 
        }
    },
    
    { label: 'Preview', type:  'button', typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Preview',  name: 'Preview',  variant: 'brand-outline',
            iconName: 'utility:preview', iconPosition: 'right'
        } 
    },
    { label: 'Download', type:  'button', typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Download', name: 'Download', variant: 'brand', iconName: 'action:download', 
            iconPosition: 'right' 
        } 
    },
    { label: 'Delete', type:  'button', typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Delete',   name: 'Delete',   variant: 'destructive',iconName: 'standard:record_delete', 
            iconPosition: 'right' 
        } 
    } 
];
export default class FilesManager extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
   @api recordId;

   @track searchFiles='';

   @track dataList;
   @track masterDataList;
    @track columnsList = columns;
    isLoading = false;

    wiredFilesResult;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.handleRefresh();
    }

    handleRowAction(event){

        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = JSON.stringify(event.detail.row);
        console.log(row);

        const parsedRow = JSON.parse(row);
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'Preview':
                this.previewFile(parsedRow);
                break;
            case 'Download':
                this.downloadFile(parsedRow);
                break;
            case 'Delete':
                this.handleDeleteFiles(parsedRow);
                break;
            default:
        }

    }

    downloadSelected() {
        const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows();
        const strinfyResult  = JSON.stringify(selectedRows);
        const parseRows = JSON.parse(strinfyResult);
         
        console.log("getSelectedRows => ", parseRows );

        let contentStr = '';
        parseRows.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row.id)
            if(contentStr == ''){
                contentStr = row.downloadUrl;
            }
            else{
                contentStr = contentStr  + '/'+row.latestVersionId;
            }
            
        });
        console.log(contentStr);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: contentStr
                }
            }, false 
        );
    }

    previewFile(file){
      
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                    pageName: 'filePreview'
                    
                    
                },
                state : {
                    selectedRecordId: file.id
                }
            });
        
        
    }

    downloadFile(file){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: file.downloadUrl
                }
            }, false 
        );
    }

    handleDeleteFiles(row){

        this.isLoading = true;

        deleteContentDocument({
            recordId : row.id
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.dataList  = this.dataList.filter(item => {
                return item.id !== row.id ;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('**** error **** \n ',error)
        })
        .finally(()=>{
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }

   
    handleRefresh(){

        this.isLoading = true;
        getFilesList({
            recordId : this.recordId
        })
        .then(result => {
            // let finalData = result;
            // finalData.forEach(file => {
            //     file.downloadUrl = file.downloadUrl;
            //     file.fileUrl     = file.contentUrl;
            //     file.CREATED_BY  = file.createdBy;
            //     file.icon = file.iconName;
            //     // file.isSelected = file.isSelected;
                
            // });
            this.dataList = result;
            this.masterDataList = result;
            console.log(this.dataList);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
        .finally(()=>{
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }

    handleFilesChange(event){
        console.log('>>> searchFiles... '+ event.target.value);
        this.searchFiles = event.target.value;
        let regex = new RegExp(this.searchFiles, "i");
        this.dataList = this.masterDataList.filter(row => regex.test(row.title));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but maybe I can help?  Managed to get this working.  Did you have `thumbNailImageTable.html` in the same directory as your `fileManager` LWC?